# how do check config before overwrite?

Tags: magento2, configuration

i has file di.xml i my module

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Xanka\MyMenu\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

how to check if my config before overwrite `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`

Answer (score 3):

You could write an integration test which requests the original Object from the objectmanager and then asserts that the instance is your new one. Heres a tutorial on how to get the Integration tests running from David Alger:

http://davidalger.com/development/magento/running-the-magento-2-test-suite/

and here are some very short but very helpful video tutorials on TDD with Magento2 from Vinai Kopp: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRFDWo7jTlrpEsJxzc7WyPw

You could also just change something in the Block and see if the Menu changes. Or even break something and see if an error occurs.